# How to load my own YOLOv8-Pose custom trained model to my react app

Tags: reactjs, deployment, yolov8

I want to load my own yolov8-pose model and capture the realtime camera feed and process these frames and then print out the results on console log. Yolov8-pose can be exported to many formats and I don't know which is the perfect format to integrate it with a react app. Basically I want to check My models FPS and latency on edge devices(I don't want to deploy it right now but this all I want for now) The given code I have tried to convert the .pt to .tflite and load but couldn't for some reason. Are there any better ways to load my own model and then process a realtime webcam feed.

````
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Webcam from "react-webcam";
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-core';
import * as tflite from '@tensorflow/tfjs-tflite';

function App() {
  const webcamRef = useRef(null);
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  //  Load posenet
  const runModel = async () => {
    const model = "upload my yolo_pose model" // Replace with the correct path

    setInterval(() => {
      detect(tfliteModel);
    }, 100);
  };


  const detect = async (tfliteModel) => {
    if (
      typeof webcamRef.current !== "undefined" &&
      webcamRef.current !== null &&
      webcamRef.current.video.readyState === 4
    ) {
      // Get Video Properties
      const video = webcamRef.current.video;
      const videoWidth = webcamRef.current.video.videoWidth;
      const videoHeight = webcamRef.current.video.videoHeight;

      // Set video width
      webcamRef.current.video.width = videoWidth;
      webcamRef.current.video.height = videoHeight;

      // Make Detections
      const resizedVideo = tf.browser.fromPixels(video).resizeBilinear([256, 256]);
      let outputTensor = tfliteModel.predict(resizedVideo);
        console.log(outputTensor.dataSync());

     
    }
  };

  

  runModel();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Webcam
          ref={webcamRef}
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            marginLeft: "auto",
            marginRight: "auto",
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            textAlign: "center",
            zindex: 9,
            width: 640,
            height: 480,
          }}
        />

        <canvas
          ref={canvasRef}
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            marginLeft: "auto",
            marginRight: "auto",
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            textAlign: "center",
            zindex: 9,
            width: 640,
            height: 480,
          }}
        />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;```
````